# What is the occupation measure for constrained risk-averse markov decision processes with only expectation constraints (no risk constraints)?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, risk-assessment

I have formulated my optimization problem as a constrained risk averse markov decision process. In my solution methodology I want to use occupation measure of the formulated problem.
I have searched many related databases and journals but cannot find the occupation measure.
I am new to the field, so please guide me in this regard!!